# Automate InfoPath form design tasks?

Tags: microsoft-infopath

I'm currently designing a rather complex form for a client.  I would like the client to be able to update the form themselves in the future.  The tasks they'll be required to do are more complex than they would like.

Is there way to script, or automate form design tasks within InfoPath?

Thanks

Comment: You gotta be way way more specific.  Automate what? The actions? The rules? The creation of controls? The editing of controls? Where are the forms published? Where do they submit to??

Answer (score 0):

Seeking to have some sort of batch file or otherwise by which I could quickly publish a form once I had made some changes, I asked a [similar question here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51830/how-to-automate-the-publishing-of-infopath-form-as-administrator-approved-templa).  Hopefully it will help someone.

Your post was in December, so you've probably either given up or moved on or solved it my now.  But, at least now there is an answer for your question!